# Replacing NULLS by some value in a SQL table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite3 database (using Python), Tweet Table (TwTbl) that has some values in the column geo_id. Most of the values in this column are NULL\None. I want to replace/update all NULLS in the geo_id column of TwTbl by a number 999. I am not sure about the syntax. I am trying the following query, but I am getting an error ("No such Column: None")

```
c.execute("update TwTbl SET geo_id = 999 where geo_id = None").fetchall()
```

I even tried using Null instead of None, that did not give any errors but did not do any update.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.  `NULL` is a special value in most database implementations that neither equal nor non-equal, it's indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer, so that you can accept it if you're inclined.

You need `Is Null` instead of `= Null`.  `Null` is a special value that's indeterminate, and neither equal nor non-equal in most database implementations.